# How to Create a Multi Line Graph

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R. I want to create a multiple line graph that shows how many people come into our library per month from 2019 to 2021. I created an Excel with three sheets (2019, 2020, 2021) with each sheet two variables - Month and Patron Count. This is the code I've developed so far:

```
install.packages("readxl"
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

## Load libraries

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
```

## Import excel file and get sheet names

```
sht = excel_sheets("-/Desktop/patron stats .xlsx")
sht
```

## Read each sheet into a list

```
df = lapply(setNames(sht, sht), functions(s) read_excel("patron stats . xlsx", sheet=s))
df
```

## Convert to a single data frame with a column for the source sheet

```
df = bind_rows(df, .id="Sheet")
```

## Visualization

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=Month, y='Patron Count', group = "Patron Count"))
geom_line()
geom_point()
ylab("Patron COunt")
```

Please help I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What error are you having? I'm guessing group should be Sheet but it's not clear what's going wrong.

Comment: Try using back ticks instead of normal quotes to map the variables. And add a `+` at the end of each lines, like this: `ggplot(data = df,aes(x=Month, y=\`Patron Count\`, group = \`Patron Count\`)) +
geom_line()`

Comment: Ella, I guess combining my data into one sheet wasn't the good choice to go since it just gave me one line as oppose to three for 2019, 2020, and 2021. Johan, thank you for suggesting adding + ! Doing so added a line to my graph.

Comment: Instead of combining my data into one sheet/data frame, I left it as three through the following code:                                                              
stat_list = lapply(setNames(sht, sht), function(s) read_excel("patron stats .xlsx", sheet=s))
stat_list
head(stat_list)                                                                                                  Now I'm not sure if this will make it easier to graph the data for the  three years.